# How to generalize some data points over time?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I have a continuous variable that measures violence in many geographic areas across four time points - four years.

I want to use this data to say in a simple manner for each region, whether or not - in general - violence is decreasing or increasing over time.

Here is an example of two regions over time:

```
region1 <- c(340, 330, 550, 320)
region2 <- c(1030, 643, 496, 295)
```

region2 is very straightforward, it is clearly decreasing substantially over time.

region1 is not so easy to simply explain. It is decreasing slightly over time but also has a large spike in one year.

I am looking for advice regarding how to think about this data and ways in which I can use it to get a general trend for each region. I am hoping a mathematical option might be available to reduce subjectivity in whether or not single outliers in a year are unimportant to the trend.

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: Does this variable measure all violence (as reported to the authorities, say) or does it estimate it from data?  If it is an authoritative measure (such as total homicides per year within a given region), then your task is one of description.  Otherwise, you need to account for estimation error as well and qualify your description with assessments of that error.

Comment: It is a measure of all violence as reported to authorities, but certainly its not complete. Given this, do you have any thoughts on how you might describe such data simply?

Comment: note that "as reported to authorities" stats for violent crime are very incomplete. For instance, in Australia the reporting rate for assault is about 30%. Reporting rates are likely to vary widely between countries, and even within a country they can be significantly changed by social and political factors, or in administrative changes in how such data is compiled. I would strongly recommend seeking advice from somebody who has experience with such issues, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

I'll need to start with a caveat: this is a complex question that touches on several tricky areas of statistical theory and practice. I don't think it's possible to give a full answer on this forum (and I'm certainly not the person to give that answer). If you're planning to use this information for making important decisions, or you want to publish your conclusions and have them stand up to scrutiny, then you're probably best off hiring a statistical consultant. What I'm presenting here is just a *very* simplified approach to the problem.

First step is to make sure you're comparing apples to apples - make sure your sources are using comparable definitions of data and measuring it in the same sort of way. Little things like a change to the definition of "violent crime" or how it's reported can make huge differences to the findings. As I noted in my comment above, a lot of crime isn't reported to police, and you'll need to consider how that may affect your inputs.

Once you've done that, your next step is probably going to be to fit a model to the data. The simplest approach would be a linear regression model, using software that gives you uncertainty information or confidence intervals for the slope of the line. The slope of the line will give you information about whether the relevant series is increasing or decreasing over time; the uncertainty in that slope parameter will tell you how reliable that information is.

This assumes that linear regression is an appropriate way to model the data, i.e. that crime stats tend to follow a linear trend over time with normally-distributed "noise". This is not necessarily a good assumption. Crime rates may show non-linear movements and can even change abruptly - for instance, if you decriminalise marijuana, your stats for marijuana offences will drop to zero overnight! Non-normally-distributed errors may also be an issue, especially when you're looking at data based on small counts.

There are more sophisticated methods designed to handle this sort of issue: time-series analysis, non-parametric regression, etc. etc. Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, none of them are likely to give much information on such a short time series. Even if you accept the assumptions and limitations of linear regression, you will quite likely find that there's a lot of uncertainty in your trend estimates, because four points just isn't much to work with. Are you able to get a longer time series?

Apologies for giving an answer that's probably rather less helpful than you were hoping for. Unfortunately, this is a tough problem!

Comment: Thanks for your time! I do have monthly data that I have aggregated into yearly data for four years, but I am not necessarily after time series estimates here. I am just looking to characterize the regions change in reported violence given the data, through a summary statistic of sorts that you can look at quickly. 

Taking sum(t1-t2, t2-t3, t3-t4) makes substantive sense given case knowledge of the regions. However it does have its draw backs, as the regions with the biggest rate of increase/decrease in violence seize the top spot as having the greatest rate of change.

Comment: Thus I know of regions which have had important qualitative changes in violence, but because their rate of change is not as significant as others, they do not seize the top spot. These regions are still characterized appropriately through the method above sum(t1-t2, t2-t3, t3-t4) - as declining in violence.

Answer (score 0):

You need some how to be able to represent numbers for each region which is saying that the violence in the last X years decreases or better then , I will take your current example and will try to think with you together :

The difference/change between numbers/number of violence in ea year :

region1 : 10,-220,230
region2 : 387,147,201

Now , Lets take the number of times there was positive/negative change and the total change size:

region1 : 2 positive = 230+10= 240, 1 negative = 220
 region2 : 4 positive = 387+147+147+201 = 882 , 0 negative = 0

Now we can average and say something about each region :

region1 in the last 4 years had ~ 240/2= 120 positive changes and ~220 negative changes.

region2 in the last 4 years had ~ 882/4 = 220 positive changes and ~0 negative changes.

conclusion :

The total change for region 1 : ~120-220 = -100
The total change for region 2 : ~220

region 1 is more violent then region 2.

Now....I know this is not exactly what you are looking for but this can give you some sense about which way you should look for (:

Comment: This is an interesting way to think about the data! Taking your idea further, does this make sense to do?

For the regions, you can take the sum of the difference from each time period to the next. So region1 = -10 +220 -230 or -20. Region2 = -387 -147 -201 or -735. In other words, both regions are becoming less violent, but region2 is becoming less violent at a **much greater** rate.

Comment: This method doesn't make sense. Averaging the magnitude of the positive and negative changes, without considering how *many* of each there are, will lead to nonsense conclusions. For example: suppose Region A has figures of 400, 500, 410, 420 (i.e. +100, -90, +10) and Region B has 400, 490, 390, 380 (+90, -100, -10). For A, the average increase is (100+10)/2 = 55 and the average decrease is -90/1 = -90; for B the average increase is 90/1 = 10 and the average decrease is (-100-10)/2 = -55. From those measures, it appears that A is increasing less and decreasing more than B - which isn't true.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey - Any thoughts on my additive solution?

Comment: @Geoffrey Brent , from your example region A : +55 , -90 , B: +90,-55, this numbers should say something about the average change. A change = -35 , B change = 35 . . . The average absolute change SIZE is same, But A is more increasing then decreasing comparing to B, A is more violence. -35 << 35 .

Comment: @JohnStud With that approach, in effect you're simply subtracting the first data point from the last: region 1 320 - 340 = -20, region 2 295 - 1030 = -735, with the intermediate values having no effect on the final result. This does give you the total increase/decrease over that time, but it doesn't take the volatility of the data into account so it can't tell you whether you're observing a meaningful trend or just noise in the data.

Comment: @StavBodik Yes, and that's the problem with this analysis - clearly A is increasing relative to B, but in looking only at averages, A appears to be decreasing.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent Thanks again for you feedback! I am indeed interested in the relative over time change. Is there some way to also capture the volatility or a different way to capture over time change from t1 to t4?

Comment: @JohnStud will post as an answer, it's too long for comments.